# bottomNavigationView destinations can be positioned horizontally instead of stacked

Tags: android, material-design, landscape, bottomnavigationview

What I want to do is that BottomNavigation view in my Android project behaves like the IOS one. When I rotate Iphone to landscape, bar has less height and icons are on the side of the text.

When the mobile is in vertical position, text and icons should be stacked.

[image]
And when I rotate to landscape, text and icons should appear horizontally like this.
[image]
Those pics are from material documentation:
https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#placement

But I can´t find how to do the second option when I rotate to landscape. Anyone knows?

Thanks!

Comment: hello! Did you find a solution?

Comment: You can find the feature request on GitHub: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1708

Comment: Hi! They decided to not implement this feature for the BottomNavigationView of material-components. 
Here is my assumption why (because it wasn't included in Material Design 3 guidelines) https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1708#issuecomment-1207479184
And here answer from one of contributor with the confirmation https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1708#issuecomment-1208164810, after that he closed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it by creating custom layout.
Example of `item_bottom_navigation_bar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then I've added it to each item of my BottomNavigationView:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
BottomNavigationMenuView navigationMenuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) mBinding.bottomNavigation.getChildAt(0);
Menu menu = mBinding.bottomNavigation.getMenu();
for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
    BottomNavigationItemView view = (BottomNavigationItemView) navigationMenuView.getChildAt(i);
    View itemBottomNavigation = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_bottom_navigation_bar, null, false);
    ((ImageView) itemBottomNavigation.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageDrawable(menu.getItem(i).getIcon());
    ((TextView) itemBottomNavigation.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(menu.getItem(i).getTitle());
    view.removeAllViews();
    view.addView(itemBottomNavigation);
}
```

Where `mBinding.bottomNavigation` is your View (maybe findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView) )

I hope it's will help you!

Comment: Does it behave like material bottom navigation? I mean, selection animation, etc

Comment: @StayCool I don't think it will. Actually, Not with this much code.